# Is it possible to mix jqwik @Property methods and junit5 @Test methods in the same test file?

Tags: junit5, jqwik

Im porting some Python code using hypothesis, and trying to keep the sources as close as possible. The python test file has both parameterized and non-parameterized methods. If I mark them all as @Property, the non-parameterized (and so identical) methods get called 1000 times.

Just learning jqwik, so may be missing something easy. If not, ill just break them into two files. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example based tests jqwik has the annotation `@Example`, which will run your test method just a single time. Use it for your non-parameterized tests.